# jq parsing date to timestamp

Tags: datetime, awk, sed, jq

I have the following script:

```
curl -s -S 'https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-NBT&tickInterval=thirtyMin&_=1521347400000' | jq -r '.result|.[] |[.T,.O,.H,.L,.C,.V,.BV] | @tsv | tostring | gsub("\t";",") | "(\(.))"'
```

This is the output:

```
(2018-03-17T18:30:00,0.00012575,0.00012643,0.00012563,0.00012643,383839.45768188,48.465051)
(2018-03-17T19:00:00,0.00012643,0.00012726,0.00012642,0.00012722,207757.18765437,26.30099514)
(2018-03-17T19:30:00,0.00012726,0.00012779,0.00012698,0.00012779,97387.01596624,12.4229077)
(2018-03-17T20:00:00,0.0001276,0.0001278,0.00012705,0.0001275,96850.15260027,12.33316229)
```

I want to replace the date with timestamp.

I can make this conversion with date in the shell

```
date -d '2018-03-17T18:30:00' +%s%3N
1521325800000
```

I want this result:

```
(1521325800000,0.00012575,0.00012643,0.00012563,0.00012643,383839.45768188,48.465051)
(1521327600000,0.00012643,0.00012726,0.00012642,0.00012722,207757.18765437,26.30099514)
(1521329400000,0.00012726,0.00012779,0.00012698,0.00012779,97387.01596624,12.4229077)
(1521331200000,0.0001276,0.0001278,0.00012705,0.0001275,96850.15260027,12.33316229)
```

This data is stored in MySQL.

Is it possible to execute the date conversion with jq or another command like awk, sed, perl in a single command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an all-jq solution that assumes the "Z" (UTC+0) timezone.

In brief, simply replace `.T` by:

```
((.T + "Z") | fromdate | tostring + "000")
```

To verify this, consider:

#### timestamp.jq

```
[splits("[(),]")]
| .[1] |= ((. + "Z")|fromdate|tostring + "000")  # milliseconds
| .[1:length-1]
| "(" + join(",") + ")"
```

#### Invocation

```
jq -rR -f timestamp.jq  input.txt
```

#### Output

```
(1521311400000,0.00012575,0.00012643,0.00012563,0.00012643,383839.45768188,48.465051)
(1521313200000,0.00012643,0.00012726,0.00012642,0.00012722,207757.18765437,26.30099514)
(1521315000000,0.00012726,0.00012779,0.00012698,0.00012779,97387.01596624,12.4229077)
(1521316800000,0.0001276,0.0001278,0.00012705,0.0001275,96850.15260027,12.33316229)
```

Comment: jq wins, simply replace .T ,shorter code. Thanks once again!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unportable awk solution.  It is not portable because it relies on the system `date` command; on the system I'm using, the relevant invocation looks like: `date -j -f "%Y-%m-%eT%T" STRING "+%s"`

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
  NF==0 { next }
  { sub(/\(/,"",$1);
    cmd="date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%eT%T\" " $1 " +%s";
    cmd | getline $1;
    $1=$1 "000";     # milliseconds
    printf "%s", "(";
    print;
  }' input.txt
```

#### Output

```
(1521325800000,0.00012575,0.00012643,0.00012563,0.00012643,383839.45768188,48.465051)
(1521327600000,0.00012643,0.00012726,0.00012642,0.00012722,207757.18765437,26.30099514)
(1521329400000,0.00012726,0.00012779,0.00012698,0.00012779,97387.01596624,12.4229077)
(1521331200000,0.0001276,0.0001278,0.00012705,0.0001275,96850.15260027,12.33316229)
```

Comment: I modified the command date: awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NF==0 { next } { sub(/\(/,"",$1); cmd="date -d  " $1" +%s%3N"; cmd | getline $1; printf "%s", "("; print;}';  this works but it takes the date gmt from the system. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution with sed :

```
 sed -e 's/(\([^,]\+\)\(,.*\)/echo "(\$(date -d \1 +%s%3N),\2"/g' | ksh
```

test :

```
  <commande_curl> | sed -e 's/(\([^,]\+\)\(,.*\)/echo "(\$(date -d \1 +%s%3N),\2"/g' | ksh
```

or :

```
  <commande_curl> > results_curl.txt
  cat results_curl.txt | sed -e 's/(\([^,]\+\)\(,.*\)/echo "(\$(date -d \1 +%s%3N),\2"/g' | ksh
```